# How to install two Ries KV?

Tags: riak

Installed Riak KV in /etc/riak.
How to install another version of Riak KV on the same computer?

I have riak 2.2.0

```
uname -a
Linux riak-2 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri May 6 14:54:05 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll have to handle port number conflicts, directory conflicts, etc. If what you want is to experiment or evaluate, use Docker containers. Why do you need two Riak KV versions on the same machine?

Comment: Because there are not enough resources.
The docker would not be desirable to use because under it nothing is ready.
Just compile Riak to another place like that?